Harvesting from a GeoNetwork 4.4.0 catalog
I am trying to harvest metadata from a GeoNetwork 4.4.0 catalog (https://somosatlantico.ipma.pt/geonetwork/) to a 4.2.9 catalog.
What kind of harvester should I use?
I selected the "GeoNetwork (from 2.1 to 3.x)" harvester but I am getting an error:

"Connect to somosatlantico.ipma.pt:443
[somosatlantico.ipma.pt/193.137.20.123] failed: Connection timed out
(Connection timed out)".

Any hint?

Try the CSW ~ https://somosatlantico.ipma.pt/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&request=GetCapabilities

Thanks, but I got the same error. Could it be network/proxy issues?

CSW service is giving quick responses for me in a browser, for example https://somosatlantico.ipma.pt/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetRecords&typenames=gmd:MD_Metadata&resultType=results  so assume the timeout issue is at your end

Is your server able to access internet? Do you use a proxy for going out of the intranet?
